# Is there anyway to show the broken image (link) icon using CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, css, image

I want to display the broken image (link) icon for certain objects on a page.  I assumed since most browsers have their own way of showing that a link is broken, that it might be something native that can be called?  Is there anyway to force it to display using JS/CSS?

Reference:
http://sitesbyjoe.com/posts/detail/2012/03/15/make-firefox-show-broken-images

Clarification:
I know I can just overlay the div with a  tag with broken src, but I'm looking for a CSS/JS solution.

Sample:

```
<div id="someid" style="background-image:url('someurlthatdoesntexist')"
</div>
```

Comment: Why would have broken images or link in first place. Is it not better to fix that rather than finding mechanism to cover up the broken stuff?

Comment: `onerror` attribute of the img tag can help you set custom image, and that will be uniform across browsers.

Comment: @Learner He's not trying to cover up broken stuff. He wants to make something normal look like it's a broken link. Not sure why.

Comment: Aah, I see. But strange requirement.

Comment: I am using "background-img" css tag for some divs.  Other people are responsible for determining the content that goes into them.  The console catches when the link is broken, but it doesn't render a broken image icon.  As it stands, I catch the errors and provide a link (onclick) for the user to fix the issue, but I'd like to include the broken image icon instead of putting "BROKEN IMAGE" or similar text over it.

Comment: Then why not just set the source to an image that looks like broken image?

Comment: Doesn't alt tag help you? alt="Your broken text message"?

Comment: It's a div with `background-image: url('someurlthatdoesntwork')`, I could overlay it and know how to overlay it with an image, but wanted to know if there was a way using JS/CSS to force the broken image icon somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PLAIN HTML

```
  <img src="idontexist.jpg"/>
```

Comment: I know it can be down in HTML like that, but I wanted a CSS/JS solution to do it dynamically instead of adding new elements to my DOM.

Comment: How will you display it without adding elements?

Comment: This is what I was originally looking at: http://sitesbyjoe.com/posts/detail/2012/03/15/make-firefox-show-broken-images

Comment: Notice your link only displays the icon if the document already has an IMG element which is broken.

Comment: It was just an example.  I wanted to know if there is a CSS/JS way to display the browser's default broken image icon at my discretion.  At any rate, I'll leave this question open for a bit more, and if I get no response I'll mark yours at the accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Save yourself a `GET` by using a *dataURI*

JavaScript;

```
var img = new Image(); // or document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'data:image/jpg,'; // data URI that will produce error
document.body.appendChild(img); // and append, for example
```

HTML;

```
<img src="data:image/jpg," />
```

Comment: I do like the data URI use!